# Printing debug output into browser console in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, firebug, firephp

Could you suggest how to print any debug data into browser console in Symfony 2?
  Especially, is it possible to implement with Symfony `VarDumper Component`?
In Zend Framework you can use tool `Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug` to do so which is very helpful. Does Symfony has something like this from the box?

Comment: what difference with varDumper in symfony toolbar I don't understand ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monolog, the logger used by Symfony, has a built-in support for FirePHP and ChromePHP.

In Symfony Standard Edition you can [configure monolog handlers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/index.html) in your application configuration.

FirePHP and ChromePHP handlers are even [present in `config_dev.yml`, but are commented out](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/f04800e803d896069ea1c03856ad717aa165190d/app/config/config_dev.yml#L26-L28):

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: [!event]
        console:
            type:   console
            channels: [!event, !doctrine]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type:   firephp
        #    level:  info
        #chromephp:
        #    type:   chromephp
        #    level:  info
```

All you need to do to see your logs in the browser is to uncomment the needed handler.

Currently, the [VarDumper component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/index.html) doesn't support dumping anything to the browser's console. However, you can see the dumped values in the web debug toolbar (or in html if you don't use the toolbar).

Comment: What do you mean by "Currently, the VarDumper component doesn't support dumping anything to the browser" , it does.

Comment: I meant the browser's console. Updated.

Comment: Is there a way to use dump() with this method? It doesn't seems to work in my side, despite var_dumper() works well.